# Conditional Compilation in Perl

Tags: perl, conditional-compilation

How do I get the following code to work?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

if ($^O eq 'MSWin32' || $^O eq 'MSWin64') {
    use Win32;    
    Win32::MsgBox("Aloha!", MB_ICONINFORMATION, 'Win32 Msgbox');     
}
else {
    print "Do not know how to do msgbox under UNIX!\n";
}
```

The above runs under Windows.  But under UNIX, there is a compilation error as Win32 cannot be found.   Replacing "use" with "require" makes things worse -- the code would fail to compile under both Windows and UNIX because the line containing MB_ICONINFORMATION is always compiled and "MB_ICONINFORMATION" would be an undeclared bare-word.

So how do I get around this problem?

Comment: I don't think `$^O` is ever `MSWin64`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perl compiles code first to an intermediate representation, then executes it. Since the `if` is evaluated at runtime but the `use` is handled during compilation, you are not importing the module conditionally.

To fix this, there are a number of possible strategies:

- conditional import with the `use if` pragma
- conditional import with a BEGIN block
- `require` the module
- defer compilation with `eval`

To import a module only when a certain condition is met, you can use the [`if` pragma](https://metacpan.org/pod/if):

```
use if $^O eq 'MSWin32', 'Win32';
```

You can also run code during compilation by putting it into a BEGIN block:

```
BEGIN {
  if ($^O eq 'MSWin32') {
    require Win32;
    Win32->import;  # probably not necessary
  }
}
```

That BEGIN block behaves exactly the same like the above `use if`.

Note that we have to use `require` here. With a `use Win32`, the module would have been loaded during the compile time of the begin block, which bypasses the `if`. With `require` the module is loaded during runtime of the begin block, which is during compile time of the surrounding code.

In both these cases, the `Win32` module will only be imported under Windows. That leaves the `MB_ICONINFORMATION` constant undefined on non-Windows systems. In this kind of code, it is better to not import any symbols. Instead, use the fully qualified name for everything and use parentheses for a function call (here: `Win32::MB_ICONINFORMATION()`). With that change, just using a `require` instead of an `use if` may also work.

If you need code to be run later, you can use a string-eval. However, this potentially leads to security issues, is more difficult to debug, and is often slower. For example, you could do:

```
if ($^O eq 'MSWin32') {
    eval q{
        use Win32;    
        Win32::MsgBox("Aloha!", MB_ICONINFORMATION, 'Win32 Msgbox');     
        1;
    } or die $@;  # forward any errors
}
```

- Because `eval` silences any errors by default, you must check success and possibly rethrow the exception. The `1` statement makes sure that the eval'ed code returns a true value if successful. `eval` returns `undef` if an error occurs. The `$@` variable holds the last error.
- `q{...}` is alternative quoting construct. Aside from the curly braces as string delimiters it is exactly the same as `'...'` (single quotes).

If you have a lot of code that only works on a certain platform, using the above strategies for each snippet is tedious. Instead, create a module for each platform. E.g.:

Local/MyWindowsStuff.pm:

```
package Local::MyWindowsStuff;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32;

sub show_message {
  my ($class, $title, $contents) = @_;
  Win32::MsgBox("Aloha!", MB_ICONINFORMATION, 'Win32 Msgbox');
}

1;
```

Local/MyPosixStuff.pm:

```
package Local::MyPosixStuff;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub show_message {
  warn "messagebox only supported on Windows";
}

1;
```

Here I've written them to be usable as classes. We can then conditionally load one of these classes:

```
sub load_stuff {
  if ($^O eq 'MSWin32') {
    require Local::MyWindowsStuff;
    return 'Local::MyWindowsStuff';
  }
  require Local::MyPosixStuff;
  return 'Local::MyPosixStuff';
}

my $stuff = load_stuff();
```

Finally, instead of putting a conditional into your code, we invoke the method on the loaded class:

```
$stuff->show_message('Aloha!', 'Win32 Msgox');
```

If you don't want to create extra packages, one strategy is to eval a code ref:

```
sub _eval_or_throw { my ($code) = @_; return eval "$code; 1" or die $@ }

my $show_message =
  ($^O eq 'MSWin32') ? _eval_or_throw q{
    use Win32;
    sub {
      Win32::MsgBox("Aloha!", MB_ICONINFORMATION, 'Win32 Msgbox');
    }
  } : _eval_or_throw q{
    sub {
      warn "messagebox only supported on Windows";
    }
  };
```

Then: `$show_message->()` to invoke this code. This avoids repeatedly compiling the same code with `eval`. Of course that only matters when this code is run more than once per script, e.g. inside a loop or in a subroutine.

Comment: Thanks Amon!   eval idea works.  (I didn't know that the eval block was compiled later.)      But the other idea does not seem to work.   Is "use if ... "
 the same as "require Win32 if ..."?   Won't that still lead to a compilation error on the MB_ICONINFORMATION line?   Maybe I am missing something.    The real issue for me is to defer the compilation of that line.

Comment: You can also combine the `use if` technique with a custom module that contains your OS specific code.

Comment: @ShangZhang As amon said, you can do everything at runtime: `if ($^O eq 'MSWin32') { require Win32; Win32::MsgBox("Aloha!", Win32::MB_ICONINFORMATION(), 'Win32 Msgbox'); }`.

Comment: By the way, I don't think `MSWin64` is a thing. I'm running a 64-bit Perl on a 64-bit Windows OS, and it still has `$^O = 'MSWin32'`.

Comment: @melpomene You are right, this is also explained in [`perldoc perlport`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html). I just copied the code from the question. Correcting that now.

Comment: Sorry that I missed Amon's other suggestion of using Win32::MB_ICONINFORMATION()!    Too much helpful info in his reply! :)    I did try Win32::MB_ICONINFORMATION but did not realize I need to also use ().   Thanks the great help from both Mel and Amon!

Comment: Regarding MsWin64...  I just assumed that must be the keyword for Windows x64 OS.  My bad.

Comment: But I guess I can still generalize my original question a bit.   If I have a line of my own code (e.g. $x++;) that I do not want compiled under UNIX (but I do want it compiled under Windows), is eval is only (or best) way to proceed?

Comment: @ShangZhang evaling to create a code ref is a common pattern, as is loading system-specific modules. That is fairly simple to do if the system-specific modules are object-oriented. See my edit. If you have further problems, consider asking a new question, this answer is now certainly long enough

Comment: After seeing other examples, I think `Win32->import;` should be `Win32->import();`. Is there any difference?

Comment: @Agostino For *method calls*, empty parens are completely optional: `->import` and `->import()` are exactly equivalent. But the parens potentially matter for normal subroutines.